# Python - file.write break loop before finishing

Tags: python, file

```
def exportOrders(self):

    file = open("orders.txt", 'w')
    file.write("\"Date\"  \"Pair\" \"Amount bought/sold\" \"Pair Price\" \"Profit/Loss\" \"Order Type\"" + '\n')
    for x in self.tradeHistory:

        date = x['date']
        pair = self.currentPair
        amount = x[self.currentPair]
        price = x['price']
        order = x['Order Type']

        if order == "buy":
            spent = x['spent']

            file.write(date + ' ' + pair + ' ' + amount + ' '
                       + price + ' ' + float(-spent) + ' ' + order + ' \n')
        if order == "sell":
            obtained = x['obtained']

            file.write(date + ' ' + pair + ' ' + amount + ' '
                       + price + ' ' + obtained + ' ' + order + ' \n')

    file.close()
```

self.tradeHistory is a list of dictionaries that store a date, a pair, the amount bought, the price of the pair, the money spent or obtained, and the order type.

My problem is that when the program runs for the first time into:

```
if order == "buy":
    spent = x['spent']

    file.write(date + ' ' + pair + ' ' + amount + ' '
              + price + ' ' + str(float(-spent)) + ' ' + order + ' \n')
```

The for loop breaks out and the orders.txt only shows the first line which is:

```
file.write("\"Date\"  \"Pair\" \"Amount bought/sold\" \"Pair Price\" \"Profit/Loss\" \"Order Type\"" + '\n')
```

Thank you in advance!

---

edit:

Basically, my self.tradeHistory has the following content

```
{'date': 1505161800, 'BTC_ETH': 0.7091196761422075, 'price': 0.07050996, 'spent': 0.05, 'Order Type': 'buy'}
{'date': 1505167200, 'BTC_ETH': 0.7091196761422075, 'price': 0.07079909, 'obtained': 0.050205027771963, 'Order Type': 'sell'}
{'date': 1505236500, 'BTC_ETH': 0.7032346826344071, 'price': 0.07110002, 'spent': 0.05, 'Order Type': 'buy'}
{'date': 1505251800, 'BTC_ETH': 0.7032346826344071, 'price': 0.0707705, 'obtained': 0.04976827010737831, 'Order Type': 'sell'}
{'date': 1505680200, 'BTC_ETH': 0.715374411944349, 'price': 0.06989347, 'spent': 0.05, 'Order Type': 'buy'}
{'date': 1505699100, 'BTC_ETH': 0.715374411944349, 'price': 0.071989, 'obtained': 0.05149908854146174, 'Order Type': 'sell'}
{'date': 1505733300, 'BTC_ETH': 0.6879187705515734, 'price': 0.072683, 'spent': 0.05, 'Order Type': 'buy'}
{'date': 1505745000, 'BTC_ETH': 0.6889021311187427, 'price': 0.07257925, 'spent': 0.05, 'Order Type': 'buy'}
{'date': 1505756700, 'BTC_ETH': 1.3768209016703161, 'price': 0.0732, 'obtained': 0.10078329000226714, 'Order Type': 'sell'}
...
```

There are 63 items inside the list of dictionaries. My aim is to create a .txt file that looks like

```
"Date"  "Pair" "Amount bought/sold" "Pair Price" "Profit/Loss" "Order Type"
1505161800 BTC_ETH 0.7091196761422075 0.07050996 0.05 buy
1505167200 BTC_ETH 0.7091196761422075 0.07079909 0.05 sell
...
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: `print(len(self.tradeHistory))`

Comment: hint: when you have double quotes in your literals use simple quotes to wrap them.

Comment: is your tradeHistory empty?

Comment: You try to add `float(-spent)` to a string. In my opinion you should get an error.

Comment: @Matthias: Unless of course, in code we don't see, the function's caller is catching and ignoring exceptions raised in it. If they do that, they'd get the "breaks out" they describe.

Comment: @Matthias I see your logic, I changed it into str(float(-spent)), but it still doesn't work. And worst of all I don't get any error back

Comment: @Primusa No, it's not. I added part of the content that is inside the tradeHistory list

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre would you mind going a little more in depth? do you mean when I create strings?

Comment: @JacobIRR that would print out the number of items inside the list, which is 63

Comment: yes: `'a "string" with "lots of quotes" doesn't need "escaping" when enclosed in simple quotes'`

Comment: @DanielChenYin then that means both your if checks are failing

Comment: @JacobIRR so I debugged it, the code doesn't get to run the second if statement. once it finished to read the first, when it gets to the {file.write()} the loop breaks and the program finishes

Comment: @DanielChenYin: As I mentioned, your observed behavior would occur if the caller of your function (or their caller, etc.) wrapped the execution in a `try`/`except` that suppressed the error. You need to provide a *complete* example, enough for us to reproduce, per [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not concatenate numbers with strings in Python. Use `str.format` instead:

```
file.write(
    '{} {} {} {} {} {}\n'
    .format(date, pair, amount, price, float(-spent), order)
)
```

You can also use `csv` module for a better implementation.

```
import csv

def exportOrders(self):

    with open("orders.txt", 'w') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=' ', quotechar='"')
        writer.writerow([
            'Date', 'Pair', 'Amount bought/sold', 'Pair Price',
            'Profit/Loss', 'Order Type'])
        for x in self.tradeHistory:
            date = x['date']
            pair = self.currentPair
            amount = x[self.currentPair]
            price = x['price']
            order = x['Order Type']

            if order == "buy":
                spent = x['spent']
                writer.writerow([
                    date, pair, amount, price,
                    float(-spent), order])
            if order == "sell":
                obtained = x['obtained']
                writer.writerow([
                    date, pair, amount, price,
                    obtained, order])
```